# Why do most public buses and trains have a uniform chair height?

Tags: physical

Given that different people have different heights, there seems to be for myself no reason why every chair in a bus has the same height.

There could be different rows with different height and in an uncrowded bus people could select the height they like best.

Is there a good reason to have uniform height?

Comment: Not sure this is a UX question as much as it is a cost control/manufacturing efficiency/etc question.

Comment: I second what DA01 said. It's probably has more to do with being able to manufacture the chairs in bulk at a lower cost.

Answer (score 4):

Would you rather find a seat on a crowded bus or be coerced to wait for seats of the right size to become unoccupied?
Keeping the seat heights uniform increases the mean number of users sitting comfortably at higher capacities.

In uncrowded buses, sure, different heights can be implemented. But that would involve higher manufacturing costs as you now need S, M, L and XL seats to be produced than a standard size.